# Establish canonical isomorphism in Set category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Using notation $A^B := \mathsf{Mor}_{\mathcal{SET}}(B, A)$ establish canonical isomorphisms for any sets $X, Y$ and $Z$:

$$ (Z^Y)^X \cong Z^{Y \times X} \; , \;(Z \times Y)^X \cong Z^X \times Y^X.$$

The only clue I have is that these isomorphisms should be bijections in $\mathcal{SET}$ category. But I dont understand, how can I show them, or prove. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

1. Map a function $f:X\to Z^Y$ to the function $(y,x)\mapsto f(x)(y)$ where $f(x)\in Z^Y$, i.e. $f(x)$ is a function $Y\to Z$.
2. Map a function $f:X\to Z\times Y$ to the pair of functions $(\pi_Z\circ f,\,\pi_Y\circ f)$ where $\pi_Z,\pi_Y$ are the projections from $Z\times Y$.

Can you define their inverses in a similar manner?